# Find all locations within a given distance in Android/SQLite

Tags: android, distance

I have to make an Android 2.2 application that requires to find all location within a given distance. I have the longitude and latitude for all locations I use in my app. If I want to find only the locations within 5 km how could I do that?

I use SQLite so I cannot use functions like cos,sin etc.

Comment: I would use a SQL query to limit the points to a bounding box 10km x 10km, centred on the search point. This will remove all points that are definitely more than 5km away. Then apply [the Haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=haversine) to the remaining points in Java.